# Error while creating a django forms from a list.

Tags: python, django

Error:

```
'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

forms.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms


class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TumblrForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('blog_id',)
        widgets = {
            'blog_id':forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

Form creation:

```
form = TumblrForm(instance=blogs_id) #blogs_id is a list of blog urls
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A `ModelForm` edits one instance. You can't pass it a list of urls. It needs an instance of `Blog`.

```
TumblrForm(instance=Blog.objects.get(pk=1))
```

If you want to edit multiple ModelForms, you'll want to look into django's `FormSet`.